# Get the type with specified name in the different assemblies but the same namepsace

Tags: c#, reflection, types, .net-assembly

I need to get the type with specified class name which have the same namespace in the different assemblies.

For example:

**Assembly1**

```
namespace ABCSolution.MyProject.MyCode
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

**Assembly2**

```
namespace ABCSolution.MyProject.MyCode
{
    public class Class2
    {
    }
}
```

In my cases, I don't know which assembly a specified class belongs to at runtime. So I am using the code below

```
private Type GetType(string typeName)
        {
            var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

            assemblies = assemblies.Where(x => x.FullName.StartsWith("ABCSolution.MyProject.MyCode.", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();

            foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
            {
                Type type = Type.GetType(typeName + ", " + assembly);

                if (type != null)
                {
                    return type;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

> var myType = GetType("ABCSolution.MyProject.MyCode.Class1");

My solution works fine most of times, however sometimes a null value is returned. I am not sure what happened and if I am using the correct approach.

Comment: What exactly is "sometimes"? 1) GetType("MyType") returns MyType in one run, null in a second run? 2) GetType("MyType") always returns MyType whereas GetType("SomeOtherType") returns always null?

Comment: Pitfalls in your code might be for case 1) all relevant assemblies are not yet loaded when you call AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies; case 2) double check that the FullName of each assembly really starts with ABCSolution... to which you are filtering (assemblies.Where...).

Comment: @nodots 1) all relevant assemblies are not yet loaded when you call AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies; ??? Can this happen ?

Comment: Yes, rule of thumb is they are loaded on the fly when first used by executing code, IIRC. The exact mechanism is probably more elaborated and dependent on other parameters, but bottom line is: Yes, it can happen.